# Whats wrong with this for loop to calculate the mean of each row?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I try to

-calculate the mean of each row from column 2 to 11 for my dataframe "alpha"

-add the result into column 12 of my dataframe "alpha" which currently has "NA" values

- column 1 is "locs"
- my df:

  ```
       [,1][,2][,3][,4][,5][,6][,7][,8][,9][,10][,11][,12]...[,17] 
   [1,]  A1   5   9   4   8   12  4   8  12   4    8    NA     NA
   [2,]  C3   6   10  4   8   12  4   8  12   4    8    NA     NA
   [3,]  P2   7   11  5   6   10  5   6  10   5    6    NA     NA
   [4,]  4    8   12  5   6   10  5   6  10   5    6    NA     NA
   [49,] 4    8   12  5   6   10  5   6  10   5    6    NA     NA
  ```

I am not very familiar with R and I don't understand the problem.

Those are the two different for loops I tried and the warning message:

```
> for (j in 1:49){
+   alpha[j, 12] <- mean(alpha[j,2:11])
+ }
There were 49 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> 
> for (j in 1:length(locs)) {
+   alpha$mean[j] <- mean(alpha[j,2:11])
+ }
There were 49 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> 
> warnings()
Warnmeldungen:
1: In mean.default(alpha[j, 2:11]) :
  Argument ist weder numerisch noch boolesch: gebe NA zurück
2: In mean.default(alpha[j, 2:11]) :
  Argument ist weder numerisch noch boolesch: gebe NA zurück

    data.frame':    49 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ locs: Factor w/ 49 levels "A1","C3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ sum.2009    : num  12 11 12 15 22 18 14 18 8 9 ...
 $ sum.2010    : num  14 11 13 18 22 21 15 21 16 17 ...
 $ sum.2011    : num  15 12 20 18 26 25 22 18 25 14 ...
 $ sum.2012    : num  15 13 17 25 24 20 24 28 26 20 ...
 $ sum.2013    : num  14 9 21 21 28 20 14 19 23 21 ...
 $ sum.2014    : num  21 16 28 24 32 26 19 22 7 12 ...
 $ sum.2015    : num  27 27 31 23 17 6 14 26 19 19 ...
 $ sum.2016    : num  18 18 14 23 25 22 24 39 32 15 ...
 $ sum.2017    : num  18 18 23 35 22 7 12 27 15 16 ...
 $ sum.2018    : num  25 23 25 26 20 11 12 13 7 8 ...
 $ mean        : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Then I converted "locs" from factor to numeric using:

`alpha$locs <- as.numeric(alpha$locs)`

`alpha$locs <- lapply(alpha$locs , as.numeric)`

which both worked but I still got the same error messages after running
the for loops.

Comment: Instead of using a `for loop` consider using `rowMeans`, like `rowMeans(alpha[, 2:11])`. It is much faster. Also the warning is telling you that some columns are none-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

`alpha[1, 2:11]` is a data frame with one row, not a vector, and `mean` doesn't know what to do with a data frame. A better approach would be `alpha[, 12] = rowMeans(alpha[, 2:11])`

Your approach would work just fine if `alpha` was a matrix - matrices can only have one data type, so a row or a column can be converted to a vector always. But data frames are all about *columns*, and columns can have different types. `alpha[2:11, 1]` is a vector because it's all from one column, and each column is a vector, so it's just part of a vector. But `alpha[1, 2:11]` spans several columns, and each of the columns *might* have a different type, so R keeps it as a data frame.

Another approach you could take would be to `unlist` each row to convert it to a vector, `alpha[j, 12] <- mean(unlist(alpha[j,2:11]))`. This will work, but it will be very slow compared to the `rowMeans` approach.